# Testing onbeforeunload events from Selenium

Tags: java, javascript, html, selenium, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to write a Selenium test for a web page that uses an onbeforeunload event to prompt the user before leaving. Selenium doesn't seem to recognize the confirmation dialog that comes up, or to provide a way to hit OK or Cancel. Is there any way to do this? I'm using the Java Selenium driver, if that's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write a user extension (or just some JavaScript in a storeEval etc) that tests that window.onbeforeunload is set, and then replaces it with null before continuing on from the page. Ugly, but ought to get you off the page.

Comment: I didn't end up doing this (my requirements changed such that I was better off using a regular alert anyway), but this looks like it would do the trick, and is close to how Selenium handles testing for other alerts.

Comment: it was just a matter of adding `js_eval "window.onbeforeunload=null"` before an open for me.  (selenium-client in Ruby, but you should be able to easily translate to other languages)

Answer (score 1):

I've just had to do this for an application of mine where the `onbeforeunload` handler brings up a prompt if a user leaves a page while a document is in an unsaved state. Python code:

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

The Java equivalent would be:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

If the alert does not exist, the code above will fail with a `NoAlertPresentException` so there is no need for a separate test to check the existence before accepting the prompt.

I'm running Selenium 2.43.0 but I think this has been doable for a while now.

In cases where I don't want the prompt to come up at all because that's not what I'm testing, I run custom JavaScript in the browser to set `window.onbeforeunload` to `null` before leaving the page. I put this in the test teardown code.

Answer (score 1):

faced same problem with "beforeunlaod" event listner, [LUMINUS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/luminous-javascript-event/baacpbikplogpeecclpnajnlghmcldkb/related)! a chrome addon that helps me just block the event listener in the plugin thats all..

Answer (score 0):

When I was confronted with limited control which I had over browser using Selenium, I turned to [MozLab](http://hyperstruct.net/projects/mozlab) plugin which solved my problem if only for one browser platform.