# Leaving a Selenium C# page doesn't show "do you really want to leave" prompt - why?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to write tests for our site and when I manually visit a page, enter some data and hit the back button a warning message comes up saying "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave -- Information entered may not be saved". But when I go through the same steps and issue a driver.Navigate().Back() that message doesn't come up.

This only happens in Firefox.

Anyone know why this would be suppressed and how I can get it to appear? I'm trying to test for the existence of this warning, so not having it there is a big problem!

Comment: UnhandledAlertBehavior should be set to desired... it should default to "accept and notify"... which means it'll throw an exception of "UnhandledAlert" and click "Accept" on that prompt.  That will happen on the next Selenium action.  See: https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.html

Comment: So try/catch the next webdriver action after "Navigate().Back()".  If it throws the unhandled alert exception you know that the alert was there and that Selenium clicked "OK" or "Leave Page".  I may have the default behavior wrong though... if it doesn't throw then explicitly set it when you set your webdriver options.

Comment: OR, you can handle the prompt after Navigate().Back().  See the 2nd answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164105/testing-onbeforeunload-events-from-selenium